# Excel Formula to find subject with number "1" and show output of the table header "S1,S2,S3..etc"

Tags: excel-formula

I wanted to ask if anyone can help me with the excel formula:

> IF the number of subjects<10 print the subjects header that have "1" under the subject list.

For example number 7, the output will show `[s20,s21,s36]`. I just need to print the TableHeader (column title(s)) that have the number "1" in it. I would really appreciate if any of you can help me with the formula. Thanks in advance :)

[image: sample data]

Comment: Can you show/attach your attempts so far? Also, please explain what in particular you're having an issue with.

Comment: I'm having issue to extract out the table header(S1,S2,S3.. etc) that have data number "1" in it under condition that the number of subject must be less than 10

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but works.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IF(AL2>=10;"";CONCATENATE("[";IF(B2=1;CONCATENATE($B$1;",");"");IF(C2=1;CONCATENATE($C$1;",");"");IF(D2=1;CONCATENATE($D$1;",");"");IF(E2=1;CONCATENATE($E$1;",");"");IF(F2=1;CONCATENATE($F$1;",");"");IF(G2=1;CONCATENATE($G$1;",");"");IF(H2=1;CONCATENATE($H$1;",");"");IF(I2=1;CONCATENATE($I$1;",");"");IF(J2=1;CONCATENATE($J$1;",");"");IF(K2=1;CONCATENATE($K$1;",");"");IF(L2=1;CONCATENATE($L$1;",");"");IF(M2=1;CONCATENATE($M$1;",");"");IF(N2=1;CONCATENATE($N$1;",");"");IF(O2=1;CONCATENATE($O$1;",");"");IF(P2=1;CONCATENATE($P$1;",");"");IF(Q2=1;CONCATENATE($Q$1;",");"");IF(R2=1;CONCATENATE($R$1;",");"");IF(S2=1;CONCATENATE($S$1;",");"");IF(T2=1;CONCATENATE($T$1;",");"");IF(U2=1;CONCATENATE($U$1;",");"");IF(V2=1;CONCATENATE($V$1;",");"");IF(W2=1;CONCATENATE($W$1;",");"");IF(X2=1;CONCATENATE($X$1;",");"");IF(Y2=1;CONCATENATE($Y$1;",");"");IF(Z2=1;CONCATENATE($Z$1;",");"");IF(AA2=1;CONCATENATE($AA$1;",");"");IF(AB2=1;CONCATENATE($AB$1;",");"");IF(AC2=1;CONCATENATE($AC$1;",");"");IF(AD2=1;CONCATENATE($AD$1;",");"");IF(AE2=1;CONCATENATE($AE$1;",");"");IF(AF2=1;CONCATENATE($AF$1;",");"");IF(AG2=1;CONCATENATE($AG$1;",");"");IF(AH2=1;CONCATENATE($AH$1;",");"");IF(AI2=1;CONCATENATE($AI$1;",");"");IF(AJ2=1;CONCATENATE($AJ$1;",");"");IF(AK2=1;CONCATENATE($AK$1;",");"");"]"));",]";"]")
```

Comment: Thx for the answer sir i will try it and i am really appreciate your work.. really thank you..